# O the interesting names on this site

Tags: riddle, pattern

So many interesting names here on this site. And so many patterns. Can you fill in the question marks with 2 out of 4 choices with explanation?

_  ?

_  UselessInfoMine

_  BreakingMyself

_  ?

_  CutestPenguin

_  DaveBensonPhillips

_  ComputrScientist

_  TheGenesisBloke

> Choices:
>
> 1. PotatoLatte
> 2. PiGuy314
> 3. PublicAccess
> 4. aPauIT
>
> Note: Your choices should satisfy all patterns.

Hint:

> The answers are PublicAccess and PiGuy314. Can you tell me why?

Comment: AddieElite doesn't seem to exist, is that going to be an issue?

Comment: No I do not think so.

Comment: 'AddyElite' with a 'y' does but I don't want to edit that in without knowing the pattern in case it breaks it...

Comment: Because of the comments I changed it to another name keeping all the pattern elements intact.

Comment: Just in case, is it really "aPauIT" with an uppercase I or actually "aPaulT" with a lowercase L? The first one does not exist.

Comment: Lower case L  or I does not figure into the pattern. Thanks. According to the hint given. Thanks

Comment: Can you clarify what "Your choices should satisfy all patterns" means? The most obvious pattern I can see - the names in the list are all made only of words with initial capitals (no digits or lower case initial letters), fits with two of the choices. But the hint gives a different answer which breaks that pattern.

Comment: @fljx nyy yrggre cnggreaf jung V zrnag. jung yrggre eryngrq cnggreaf lbh frr? Gurer ner 4

Answer (score 2):

Let's look at the list again, but this time with...

> the joining date for each user:
>
>
>  _ ?
>
>  _ [UselessInfoMine](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/43629/uselessinfomine) 2017-12-27
>
>  _ [BreakingMyself](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/37821/breakingmyself) 2017-6-23
>
>  _ ?
>
>  _ [CutestPenguin](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14111/cutestpenguin) 2015-07-15
>
>  _ [DaveBensonPhillips](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/11880/davebensonphillips) 2015-04-23
>
>  _ [ComputrScientist](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2241/computrscientist) 2014-09-02
>
>  _ [TheGenesisBloke](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/2164/thegenesisbloke) 2014-08-19

Now look at the choices

> 1. [PotatoLatte](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/49155/potatolatte) 2018-05-12
>
>  2. [PiGuy314](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/76863/piguy314) 2021-09-27
>
>  3. [PublicAccess](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/14220/publicaccess) 2015-07-22
>
>  4. [aPaulT](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/users/305/apault) 2014-05-29

So to keep up with the pattern of

> the user profile creation date getting older down the list, the first ? gets filled in with PiGuy314 *(or PotatoLatte)* and the second ? gets filled in with PublicAccess.

Comment: There’s a pattern of: 2 sections in name, 3 sections in name, 2, 3, 2, etc.